# How to test if an integer is divisible by 3,4,5 or 9

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It can be shown  that an integer is divisible
by 3 if, and only if, the sum of its digits is divisible
by 3. An integer is divisible by 9 if, and only if, the sum
of its digits is divisible by 9. An integer is divisible by 5 if,
and only if, its right-most digit is a 5 or a 0. And an integer
is divisible by 4 if, and only if, the number formed by its
right-most two digits is divisible by 4. Check the following
integers for divisibility by 3, 4, 5 and 9.

a. 637,425,403,705,125

b. 12,858,306,120,312

c. 517,924,440,926,512

d. 14,328,083,360,232

A. So I know that since the right hand number 25 is divisble by 5 and 3 it cannot be divisible by 4. What I get confused is how does one find the sum of digits for this a?

Comment: "Since the right hand number 25 is divisible by 5 and 3 it cannot be divisible by 4." This does not logically follow. For instance, $60$ is divisible by $5$ and $3$ and is furthermore divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the digits is:

$6+3+7+4+2+5+4+0+3+7+0+5+1+2+5=54$

Now $5+4=9$, hence 54 is divisible by 9 (this is trivial since 6*9=54).

It is divisible by $5$ because its last integer is $5$.

It is not divisible by $4$ because it is not even.

You can handle b) c) and d) in a similar fashion.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for typing too fast. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I knew what you meant.